# UITableView (IBOutlet) becomes null after initial data loaded

Tags: ios, uitableview, null, xcode4.6, reloaddata

This has been driving me mad - I have a Class ParentViewController (no xib) with @property picTable, and then ChildViewController (subclass of ParentViewController) with xib and the picTable part of File's Owner linked up.

I noticed the problem as I need to add in more data from a URLRequest - I have the data in an NSArray, but calling reloadData does nothing - and breakpoints are showing that self.picTable is then null - but it is definitely linked (checked via breakpoints) earlier in the view's lifecycle.

I've tried using NSNotificationCenter, a dispatch queue and [self performSelectorOnMainThread... all to no avail - my refreshTableView is always called but the breakpoints show the table view as null.

Tried -

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *picTable;

And -

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *picTable;

Links to the two classes:

Parent:
https://github.com/gileze33/Ticklr/blob/master/Ticklr/GWTPicPresentingViewController.h
https://github.com/gileze33/Ticklr/blob/master/Ticklr/GWTPicPresentingViewController.m

Subclass:
https://github.com/gileze33/Ticklr/blob/master/Ticklr/GWTPicViewController.h
https://github.com/gileze33/Ticklr/blob/master/Ticklr/GWTPicViewController.m

Comment: you should post the source code for both classes you mention

Comment: Just added links to the source on GitHub

Comment: Just to confirm - it seems as though all UI elements are being released straight after viewDidLoad..

Answer (score 0):

Even though you call [super initWithNibNamed...] from the subclass, I'm doubtful that the nib is hooking up the tableview to the superclass.  Even if it is important to your design to have the tableView property defined in the superclass, try moving the tableView property down to the subclass and see if it works then.

Comment: I literally just managed to fix this- it was due to me initiating my model fetcher in the initWithNib rather than viewDidLoad - must have been referencing a different instance of my view controller as the delegate some how